# Meteor Startup JQuery DOM Elements Not Ready (JQueryUI Draggable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor, startup

In the Meteor docs it says that `Meteor.startup` will be called after the DOM and all templates have been processed. However, my code within `Meteor.startup` is acting as if the DOM elements aren't there.

In .js:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  console.log($('.draggable').length);
});
```

In .html:

```
<template name="item">
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content">
  </div>
</template>
```

In the console I see:

> 0

But on the page I can see my items. And indeed if I include my JQuery in `Template.item.rendered` or in a `mouseover` event, I get the correct length of the array. So why would the `startup` function not have my DOM elements ready to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing your code looks something like this, but let me know if I'm wrong:

```
<template name="list">
  {{#each items}}
    {{> item}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

The `{{#each ...}}` helper works with a cursor object to respond to data changes on the cursor. So, in your case, if that data is coming from the server (e.g. a subscription), at the time of Meteor.startup, the data might not have been loaded yet. So initially your list will be empty. Then, as data comes off the wire a new `item` template will be rendered for each data item. If you want to make a specific item draggable, you could put that jQuery code in the `Template.item.rendered` callback.

Does this help?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. That is what I ended up doing and thanks to you, now I know the explanation.